# Bidirectional communication between respberry pi's via socket (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, pi

I got 50% of this to work - pi #1 acts as the server and sends messages to the client (pi #2).

But how can it RECEIVE information back from the client?

Basically, the issue I'm having is that pi #1 needs to receive commands from pi #2 as well.

SERVER.py

```
import socket        
import time

print("This is pizero2 as server.") 

# REMOTE SETUP as SERVER
addresses = {
    'littlechefee': {'ip': '192.168.39.242','port': 5003}, # pi4-one pi4 L wall .. liqs
    } 
sockets = [] 
i = 0 
for addr in addresses:
    ip = addresses[addr]['ip']
    port = addresses[addr]['port']
    sockets.append(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
    sockets[i].setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    try:
        sockets[i].connect((ip,port))
        print(f'Success, connected with {addr}. ')
    except:
        print("Unable to Connect Rpi with IP: {} and Port: {}".format(ip,port ))
    i += 1

def send():
    command = 'test from pizero2'
    indx = 0                                # bc only 1 remote pi 
    print(f"Sending littlechefee a cmd.")
    try:    
        sockets[indx].sendall(str(command).encode('utf-8'))
    except:
        print('Unable to send command! Invalid options')

while True:
    send()
```

CLIENT.py

```
import socket
import time

# REMOTE SETUP as CLIENT
rcv_ip = '192.168.39.46' # Please insert the receiver own ip (ip of rpi on which this script is running.) Example : '192.268.xx.xx'
rcv_port = 5002 # please use 5001 upto 5006 for different rpi's

sock_rcv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock_rcv.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock_rcv.bind((rcv_ip,rcv_port))
sock_rcv.listen(10)

def get_data():                           
    dt_r, adr_r  = sock_rcv.accept() 
    while True:
        cmd = dt_r.recv(1024)
        if cmd:
            cmd = cmd.decode('utf-8')   # str = ['dispense', [13, 6, 13], 50]
            cmd = cmd.split(' ')  # lst = ["['dispense',", '[13,', '6,', '13],', '50]']
            print("cmd is: ", cmd)          # cmd = ["['nema',", "'W',", "'5',", '3000]']

        else:
            print("Connection closed.")
            break

        time.sleep(1)

while True:
    get_data()
```

Comment: Your wording is bit misleading. The party that calls connect is usually called client and the party that calls bind/listen/accept is usually called server. If you want a bi-directional connection you can use the same socket and call dt_r.send() in the client.py and sockets[0].recv in the server.py.

Comment: The client "listens" in my case because it's the only one that can receive commands so far. Can you elaborate on your solution? Are you saying the client needs to temporarily become the server and the server needs to become the client?